# Is there a way to make a local branch immutable?

Tags: git, branch, githooks

I'm extremely stupid and sometimes I merge a "feature branch" in the wrong `master` branch as opposed to the `develop` branch and that of course leads to pain and suffering.

Since it's the second time already that this has been happening, I wonder if there's a way for me to make a branch immutable locally.

I've already tried with [this pre-commit hook](https://gist.github.com/Simbul/1781656) to prevent me from directly making commits on said branch, but this is not stopping merges as in:

```
git checkout master
git merge wip
```

Is there a way to prevent all possible changes to a local branch? If not, is it at least possible to prevent changes from being pushed?

Comment: Wrong commits and merges not a problem until you push them, you can just `reset` the master back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a local branch immutable (there is no local hook that runs before a merge operation).  However, if you're not going to be making commits on the branch, just don't check it out.  If you have it checked out already, delete the local branch:

```
$ git checkout some-other-branch
$ git branch -D master
```

Now when you attempt to checkout the `master` branch it will fail:

```
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

If you ever need to refer to the upstream `master` branch (e.g., for a `diff`), you can just refer to it directly:

```
$ git diff origin/master
```

Comment: Is there any risk that the local deletion of said branch would cause (maybe with some weird pushes) it to be delete on the remote server too?

Comment: I don't think this introduces any additional risks.

Comment: can you lock a branch by using git worktree? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree