# Lock a local git branch from any further changes

Tags: git, git-checkout

Say I have this sequence of commands:

```
current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
git checkout -b "foo"
git lock "$current_branch"   # i made this up
```

*what I want to do is lock a branch so that I cannot **accidentally** make changes to it after I am done with it. For example, after a feature branch has been squashed and merged into the integration branch.*

Is there a way to do this with git? Perhaps there is a way to lock a worktree using https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree?

Comment: What's your reason for needing this? Could a tag work just as well? See `git tag`

Comment: You could just do the low-tech "copy or rename the branch and append 'lock' to the end of the branch name" and just not touch that branch. If you don't want to make a change to a local branch, then don't don't make a change to the local branch. Do you really need to force yourself to not modify it with a locking mechanism here?

Comment: yeah honestly it would be helpful, if I changed to a temp branch and then modified all the file permissions to read only or something. I make changes to the wrong branch all the time. Once I am done with a feature branch and it gets merged, I accidentally continue working on that feature branch all the f-ing time, it kills me lol

Comment: @MattMessersmith: yes, except that branch names are forbidden from ending with the string `.lock` (see `git check-ref-format`). (You might start with `locked.` instead.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a local branch immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102161/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-local-branch-immutable)

Comment: The OP explains the use case - I want to prevent myself from accidentally working on a feature branch which has already been squashed and merged into the integration branch.

Comment: The easiest way is to create a tag on the branch tip and remove the branch altogether. Use a consistent rule to name these tags to let them explain their purposes and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

How about we roll this feature ourselves? Lets start with your `git lock` command. We can write that as an alias;

```
$ git config alias.lock "! touch .locks;
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | cat - .locks | sort | uniq > .locks.tmp;
    mv .locks.tmp .locks;"
```

Whenever we call `git lock` we're going to add the current branch to the `.locks` file which is our distinct list of locked branches.

Then create (or edit) `.git/hooks/pre-commit` to include;

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -Fxq `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` .locks
then
    cat <<\EOF
Error: Branch is locked
EOF
    exit 1
fi
```

Which will check the `.locks` file each time we commit to make sure we're not commiting to a locked branch.

Add an entry in your `.gitignore` to ignore our new `.locks` file and you're done.

Example usage;

```
adam@lime ~/git-lock $ git checkout -b MuhBranch
Switched to a new branch 'MuhBranch'
adam@lime ~/git-lock $ git commit -m "Final changes." --allow-empty
[MuhBranch 0304f21] Final changes.
adam@lime ~/git-lock $ git lock
adam@lime ~/git-lock $ git commit -m "Just one more..." --allow-empty
Error: Branch is locked
```

Remember to make your `.git/hooks/pre-commit` executable using `chmod u+x .git/hooks/pre-commit`.

Comment: small typo: you wanted `git rev-parse` not `git ref-parse` (this is a typo I make myself all the time...).

Answer (score 1):

To lock a branch, you can use git hooks. Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6827045/3663635).

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> # lock the myfeature branch for pushing
> refname="$1"
>
> if [[ $refname == "refs/heads/myfeature" ]]
> then
>     echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
>     echo "You cannot push to myfeature! It's locked"
>     echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
>     exit 1
> fi
> exit 0
> ```

Comment: not what I am looking for, this is only for local, doesn't have to do with pushing to a remote

Comment: @AlexanderMills afaik, bitbucket provides server-side hook.

Comment: pre-commit would work yes, but I am not dealing with any remotes here

Comment: pre-commit hook is not ideal, I don't want to be able to make any changes on a certain branch - I don't want to be able to check that branch out unless I use --force or something